# How to extract comments from a Facebook account to my Webapp?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to extract all the comments from a Facebook account to my Webapp using Graph API by coverting the result into an array and then printing the array,but the result that I am getting is a blank array followed by the respective post.I don't know whats wrong.

```
if (isset($accessToken)) 
                             {     
echo 'Posts:';
echo '<br>';
// getting all posts published by user
try {
    $posts_request = $fb->get('/me/feed');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
}
$total_posts = array();
$posts_response = $posts_request->getGraphEdge();
```

$response_array = $posts_response->asArray();
    if($fb->next($posts_response)) {

```
    $total_posts = array_merge($total_posts, $response_array);
    while ($posts_response = $fb->next($posts_response)) {
        $response_array = $posts_response->asArray();
        $total_posts = array_merge($total_posts, $response_array);
    }
    foreach ($total_posts as $key) {

      if(isset($key['message'])){
       echo $key['message'];
       echo '<br>','<br>';
     }
    }
    //print_r($total_posts);
} else {

    $posts_response = $posts_request->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
    foreach ($posts_response as $key) {

      if(isset($key['message'])){
       echo $key['message'];
       echo '<br>','<br>';
       $o_id= $key['id'];
       echo $o_id;

try {
        // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
        $response = $fb->get('/113932879436074_129461837883178/comments',$accessToken);
    } 
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) 
    {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } 
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) 
    {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    $graphNode = $response->getGraphEdge();
    $comments=$graphNode->asArray();
    print_r($comments);
```

}

```
Output:
```

113932879436074_131399157689446Array ( ) #TrueStory 
113932879436074_131393101023385Array ( ) Good afternoon Pihu Jaiswal
113932879436074_129461837883178Array ( ) Super bored

Comment: You are not even trying to request the comments for the current post, but for a specific one whose ID you have hard-coded ... are you sure that one does even have comments?

Comment: @CBroe Actually I got the PHP code from the Graph API manual.Link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/comment    .........and the ID which is hard-coded is a post Id which do have comments......but this thing isn't working for me,if you have any alternate code please post it because this thing isn't working for me.

Comment: Why are you explicitly passing the access token with the second call, but not with the first one? Do things change when you make the second one without explicitly passing it? Is `113932879436074_129461837883178` actually a post your app has read access to? I would recommend that you test such requests in Graph API Explorer first, that will help you figure out whether it is a problem with your request or with your code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but,I didn't get you because I have explicitly passed the access token only once while retrieving comments.And 113932879436074_129461837883178 is a post my app has read access to.I am still stuck with the same problem,I was able to retrieve all the post on my Webapp successfully but not the comments.

Comment: _“because I have explicitly passed the access token only once while retrieving comments”_ - yes, and I asked you _why_ you do that as this point, because for your initial request that fetches the posts you are not explicitly passing it, but let the SDK take care of it. // Have you tested in Graph API Explorer yet?

Comment: oh I get it,you were right it doesn't makes a difference even if I don't pass the access token explicitly.As per your suggestion I tested this '/113932879436074_129461837883178/comments' in Graph API explorer and it doesn't works.

Comment: @CBroe tysm for your guidance I got the output.I tried this -'me?fields=id,name,posts{comments{message}}' and used graphNode insead of edge and it worked

Answer (score 0):

if($fb->next($posts_response)) {

```
    $total_posts = array_merge($total_posts, $response_array);
    while ($posts_response = $fb->next($posts_response)) {
        $response_array = $posts_response->asArray();
        $total_posts = array_merge($total_posts, $response_array);
    }
    foreach ($total_posts as $key) {

      if(isset($key['message'])){
       echo $key['message'];
       echo '<br>','<br>';
     }
    }
    //print_r($total_posts);
} else {

    $posts_response = $posts_request->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
    foreach ($posts_response as $key) {

      if(isset($key['message'])){
       echo $key['message'];
       echo '<br>','<br>';
       $o_id= $key['id'];
       echo $o_id;

try {
        // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object

        $response = $fb->get('me?fields=id,name,posts{comments{message}}');
    } 
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) 
    {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } 
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) 
    {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
    $comments=$graphNode->asArray();
    print_r($comments);
```

}